# Don't create section for bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning, chapters

I am writing a document which uses chapters (`\chapter{...}`) instead of sections and would like to create one chapter for my references. But when I am using these commands:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{ref.bib}
```

to generate my references, it automatically creates a section "Bibliography" which is not consistent with the document. So I would like to just generate the references without any section and than use the `\chapter{...}` command for sectioning.

Does anyone know how to stop the `\bibliography*` commands from creating this section?

My document uses a custom class which was provided by my university:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{uva-bachelor-thesis}[2005/06/10 Version]

\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage[absolute]{textpos}
\RequirePackage{rotating}

\def\supervisors#1{\gdef\@supervisors{#1}}
\def\signedby#1{\gdef\@signedby{#1}}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[10pt,oneside]{report}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
        \thispagestyle{empty}
    % A fake element on the page (else texpos absolute option doesn't work)
    \hspace*{1em}

    \begin{textblock*}{10cm}(6cm,3cm)
        \noindent\large\scshape Bachelor \\[2ex]
        \includegraphics[height=1cm]{logo}
        %\Large University
    \end{textblock*}

    \begin{textblock*}{10cm}(6cm,12cm)
        \noindent
        \sffamily\Huge \@title
    \end{textblock*}

    \begin{textblock*}{10cm}(6cm,18cm)
        \noindent
        \sffamily\Large \@author\\[3pc]
        \@date
    \end{textblock*}

    \begin{textblock*}{10cm}(6cm,26cm)
    \noindent\sffamily
    \begin{description}
        \item[\sffamily Supervisor:] \@supervisors
        \item[\sffamily Signed:] \@signedby
        \end{description}
    \end{textblock*}

    \textblockcolor{LightGray}
    \begin{textblock*}{2cm}(3cm,2cm)
        \vspace*{26cm}\hspace*{1em}
    \end{textblock*}

    \begin{textblock*}{2cm}(3.7cm,25cm)
        \begin{rotate}{90}
            \noindent\scshape\Huge\textcolor{DarkGray}{University}
        \end{rotate}
    \end{textblock*}

%   \cleardoublepage
}
```

Here is my main file to reproduce the problem:

```
\documentclass[oneside, openright]{uva-inf-bachelor-thesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter{\refname}}{}{}{}

\title{}
\author{}
\supervisors{}
\signedby{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{ref.bib} % The file containing the bibliography

\chapter{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Usually `\bibliography` uses a `\chapter*` command if a `book` class is used. This question is unclear. Please post the minimal version of your document that produces this, i.e. it must be compilable. Are you using `tocbibind`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I added my example. The class I am using is a custom class that my university provided.

Comment: I've compiled your example and I get a chapter heading for the bibliography, unnumbered, of course, since the special class is based on `report`, which uses `\chapter*{...}` -- you're trial to patch the command fails!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, oh yes, you're right. It used indeed the `\chapter*{...}`. In my original document I use another file which changes the styling. So the `\chapter{...}` looks really different from `\chapter*{...}`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this, what is wanted? A numbered chapter heading for `bibliography`? Then use `\usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}`.

```
\documentclass[oneside, openright]{uva-inf-bachelor-thesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter{\refname}}{}{\typeout{Foo}}{\typeout{Stuff}}

\title{}
\author{}
\supervisors{}
\signedby{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\cite{Lam94}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio} % The file containing the bibliography

\chapter{Appendix}

\end{document}
```